# Default URL for Google Analytics multi-domain tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics property set up to track 2 domains: example.com, example.org.

What should I set as my default URL in the Google Analytics property settings?

Answer (score 0):

The one you prefer, it has no influence on the tracking.